# How can i scale object slowly using StartCoroutine?

Tags: unity, c#

Both scripts attached to same object in Hierarchy.
The first script i'm using the F key to display or not display the object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DroidMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject droid;

    private float distance;
    private Camera cam;

    private void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        distance = Vector3.Distance(cam.transform.position, droid.transform.position);
        droid.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            droid.SetActive(!droid.activeInHierarchy);
        }
    }
}
```

Once pressing F to show the object i want the object to be scaled slowly from 0,0,0 to 1,1,1 so i did another script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float maxSize = 1f;
    public float growFactor = 1f;
    public float waitTime = 5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    IEnumerator Scale()
    {
        float timer = 0;

        while (true) // this could also be a condition indicating "alive or dead"
        {
            // we scale all axis, so they will have the same value, 
            // so we can work with a float instead of comparing vectors
            while (maxSize > objectToScale.transform.localScale.x)
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                objectToScale.transform.localScale += new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * Time.deltaTime * growFactor;
                yield return null;
            }
            // reset the timer

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

            timer = 0;
            while (1 < objectToScale.transform.localScale.x)
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                objectToScale.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * Time.deltaTime * growFactor;
                yield return null;
            }

            timer = 0;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (objectToScale.activeInHierarchy == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Scale());
        }
    }
}
```

But i'm getting two exceptions on the first script on the line:

```
droid.SetActive(!droid.activeInHierarchy);
```

First exception:

> Slope Limit must be smaller than 90 degrees.
>     UnityEngine.GameObject:SetActive(Boolean)
>     DroidMove:Update() (at Assets/NAVI/Scripts/DroidMove.cs:23)

Second exception:

> Step Offset must be less or equal to  +  * 2
>     UnityEngine.GameObject:SetActive(Boolean)
>     DroidMove:Update() (at Assets/NAVI/Scripts/DroidMove.cs:23)

Comment: Those exceptions are not related to the classes you've posted. They are from some other script in the droid object, that's being triggered by `SetActive(true)`.

Comment: @XenoRo i just tested now if i'm not using the ChangeScale script it's working fine. With this script it's giving the exceptions.

Comment: Btw, you aren't using `timer` at all. You set a value to the variable, but you don't *do* anything with that value.

Comment: @Draco18s I tried another script and it's working but i have with it some minor problems. So i'm not sure if to update the question with what i changed.

Comment: Also don't start a coroutine in `Update()`: You'll get a new instance of the function operating on the object every 0.02 seconds, which is *definitely* not what you want.

Comment: @Draco18s The reason i start it in the Update is that in the other script i press on F and only when i press on F and it's showing the object then i want to scale it. That is why in the Update i;'m doing a  check: if (objectToScale.activeInHierarchy == true) but that's another problem since now it's true all the time. But the logic is only when i press F in the first script and it's true showing the object then scale it in the second script.

Comment: As soon as you press F, yes, the coroutine starts. Then next frame a second copy starts, then on the next frame a third copy, a fourth, a fifth, a sixth...you need a limiter.

Comment: @Draco18s The "limiter" is probably the `GetKeyDown` in the first script... The problem is: That's being conflated with `activeInHierarchy == true` on the second script. The first will only be true once (assuming no further presses of 'F'); the second, will be true every frame that `objectToScale` is active in hierarchy. --- Basically, the OP does have a limiter... But it's being done wrong.

Comment: @XenoRo That's what I mean. While it won't start when the game starts, as soon as it's *allowed* to start, it'll start tons and tons of copies: There's nothing that restricts it to starting the coroutine *once and only once*

Comment: You should attach a script on `object` to be scaled. In that you can execute `Coroutine` *once* and only *once* in `OnEnable` method.

Comment: Sorry forgot to update that i found solution and it's working already.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's a really bad idea of Starting a Coroutine in the Update Loop. 
Never call it in Update. 
instead you should use OnEnable as coroutine of your scale shouldn't be calling every frame.